# Setting max_length of a form field using a parameter in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, parameters, maxlength

I have a parameter that I am passing in to the form.  It is a dictionary to configure the form.

How can I set the max_length of a field using a value from the dictionary?

```
class StepTwoForm(forms.Form):
    number = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'config' in kwargs:
           config = kwargs.pop('config')
           super(StepTwoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.fields['number'].max_length = config['MAX_LENGTH']
```

I also just tried hardcoding the max_length to an arbitrary value which didn't work either.

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: That should work, except that the call to `super` should be before the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will work, however you need to move the `super(..)` call outside of the condition, otherwise the form won't get setup properly.

```
from django.core import validators

class StepTwoForm(forms.Form):
    number = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        config = kwargs.pop('config', {})
        super(StepTwoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'MAX_LENGTH' in config:
            validator = validators.MaxLengthValidator(config['MAX_LENGTH'])
            self.fields['number'].validators.append(validator)
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like `max_length` and `min_length` are used upon initialization, so it's too late to set the `max_length` parameter. You need to manually add the validator. I've updated the code to reflect the change. Here is the relevant code in Django: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L186-L192

Comment: I've updated the answer after I've looked at the Django source code for the `CharField`

Comment: awesome ! props for actually looking through the source :)